# SQL Query - How to get difference of sum of multiple of cells of rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to get the difference of the sums of two fields which are in single table (really sorry if this is confusing), please read on for an example

```
Id  type    account_id  stock_id    volume  price   value
==========================================================
1   BUY      1          1             5     500     2500
2   BUY      1          4            30     200     6000
6   BUY      1          1            10     500     5000
7   SELL     1          1             3     500     1500
8   SELL     1          1             2     500     1000
9   SELL     1          4            20     120     2400
```

Above is my sample data and I would my SQL query result to be something like,

```
account_id  stock_id    volume  totalAmount
============================================
1           1           10      5000
1           4           10      3600
```

basically here I am trying to get the total buy value of unique account & stock combination and subtract with the total sell value

Any help here would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried something to get the expected result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Fiddle Test:**
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/53035/1/0

```
select   account_id,
         stock_id,
         sum(case when type = 'BUY' then volume else -volume end) as volume,
         sum(case when type = 'BUY' then value else -value end) as totalamount
from     tbl
group by account_id,
         stock_id
having   sum(case when type = 'BUY' then volume else -volume end) <> 0
```

I added the HAVING clause based on your comment.

Comment: Just what I wanted.. that too, too quick. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: how to avoid the rows which results sum(case when type = 'BUY' then volume else -volume end) to ZERO ?

Answer (score 0):

Just to reduce duplication I would change Brian's code to this:

```
SELECT 
     account_id, 
     stock_id, 
     SUM(volume * type_sign) as total_volume,
     SUM(value * type_sign) as total_value
FROM 
  (select   t.*, case when type = 'BUY' then 1 else -1 end as type_sign
   from tbl) t
GROUP BY account_id,
         stock_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select buy.account_id,buy.stock_id,(buy.volume-sell.volume) volume,(buy.totalAmount-sell.totalAmount) totalAmount from 
(select account_id,stock_id,sum(volume) volume,sum(value) totalAmount from stock 
where type = 'BUY'
group by account_id,stock_id) buy
inner join
(select account_id,stock_id,sum(volume) volume,sum(value) totalAmount from stock
where type = 'SELL'
group by account_id,stock_id) sell
on buy.account_id = sell.account_id and buy.stock_id = sell.stock_id
```